# Hibernate cant remove child (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 `Java` `Hibernate` Entities. `User` with unidirectional `oneToMany` realtion with `Filter` Entity. And `Filter` Entity has unidirectional `manyToOne` relation with `Model` entity. I want to delete only  `Filter` entity but get `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`.

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gecars`.`users_filters`, CONSTRAINT `FK_oymjo03tkarckpfjfmaak99lj` FOREIGN KEY (`filters_id`) REFERENCES `filters` (`id`))

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    ...
    //@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // old
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL) //edited but exception still occurs
    private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>(0);
```

Filter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filters")
public class Filter {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_model") 
private Model model;
...
```

delete method in DAO class:

```
public void deleteFilter(int filterId){
    String hql = "delete from Filter where id= :filterId";
    session.createQuery(hql).setInteger("filterId", filterId).executeUpdate();
}
```

or `session.delete`:

```
public void deleteFilter(int filterId){
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(getFilter(filterId));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

}
```

Comment: when you delete a particular filter what should happen to the Model rows that are using this filter id as FK? Is the intent to do a delete those Model rows as well or have null as filter id for those Model rows?

Comment: By the way, why do you want to use HQL for this delete instead of `session.delete`? Any specific use case?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I want delete only row from Filters table by specific filter id. Model  and User row must not be deleted. No specific use case for use HQL. I can use and session.delete (see edited post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using join table for the one-to-many association. I assume that you have generated your schema automatically from the mappings, so you may not be aware of that. This way when you delete `Filter`s via bulk Hibernate DML statement, the records in the join table remain and cause foreign key constraint violation.

Best approach is to define a join column on the many side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filters")
public class Filter {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user") 
  private User user;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.All, mappedBy="user")
  private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>(0);
}
```

If you don't want to use bidirectional association, you can define the join column in the `User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.All)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user")       
  private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>(0);
}
```

This way, the join column will still be in the `filters` table, thus deleting the `Filter`s will not cause foreign key violations.

Comment: I get same Exception when I use `session.delete` (see post) not DML. I want use unidirectional relation between user and filters. I tried add cascade=CascadeType.ALL to User class above filters, but Exception still occurs.

Comment: After delete `users_filters` table, and using your suggestion now I can delete filter, but now I have new problem, `model` row also deleted from database, how to delete `Filter' but skip the model?

Comment: @EdgarasKarka That should not happen with your mappings. You are sure you don't have cascade type `ALL` or `REMOVE` defined for the many-to-one association to `model`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, problem was with (cascade=CascadeType.All)  for the many-to-one association to model.